# Is there a choice homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, real-numbers, axiom-of-choice, rational-numbers

Let $\pi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Q}$ be the canonical projection. With the axiom of choice we "know" that there are choice functions $\alpha : \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\pi \circ \alpha = id_{\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Q}}$ (i.e. with $\alpha(x) \in x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Q}$).

Are there such choice functions which are group homomorphisms (with respect to addition)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Choose a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, and pick a preimage for each basis vector in $\mathbb{R}$. By mapping each basis vector to the chosen preimage, you have successfully constructed a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ that splits the quotient map. This is in particular an additive homomorphism.

More generally, any short exact sequence $$0 \to U \to V \to W \to 0 $$ of vector spaces splits.

Comment: Decided there was no point in answering, someone would type faster. You could simplify this, seems to me, by starting with a basis that contains $1$.

Comment: This cannot possibly be that simple. If for the rationals you didn't choose $0$, then $\alpha(x+\Bbb Q)+\alpha(0+\Bbb Q)\neq\alpha(x+0+\Bbb Q)=\alpha(x+\Bbb Q)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure I understand your concern. I'm defining $\alpha$ on the chosen basis, then extending by linearity. So yes, $\mathbb{Q} \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ will be mapped to $0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right. I should go to bed. (I blame the other guy from the department who sat next to me on the bus and robbed me of my usual bus nap! ;-))